# solving $\tan^{-1}(x+1)+\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}(x-1)=\tan^{-1}3$

Tags: trigonometry

solve $$\tan^{-1}(x+1)+\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}(x-1)=\tan^{-1}3$$.

---

we have the formula;

> let $$\tan^{-1}(\frac{x+y}{1-xy})=a$$ :when $xy<1$ $$\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y= a$$
> when $x>0,y>0,xy>1$ $$\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y= \pi+a$$
> when $x<0,y<0,xy>1$ $$\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y= -\pi+a$$

**My try**

$$\tan^{-1}(x+1)+\tan^{-1}(x-1)=\tan^{-1}3-\tan^{-1}x$$

when $x^2-1<1$ and $3x<1$or when $-\sqrt{2}<x<1/3...(1)$:

$$\tan^{-1}(\frac{2x}{2-x^2})=\tan^{-1}(\frac{3-x}{1+3x})$$

$$\frac{2x}{2-x^2}=\frac{3-x}{1+3x}$$solving and neglecting the ones coming out of the bound defined by $x$ in (1).

we have $x=-1$.

I know i have to do other cases when $xy>1$ . But suprisingly the answer given in book is only $x=-1$ and the solution also does not take the other cases.Why are they neglecting other cases. Morover i feel doing so many cases is very less efficient .How do i tackle this question easily?.

Comment: I feel that this problem has some spirit of JEE.

Comment: @BookOfFlames of course you guessed it right.Time management is crucial in these exams

Comment: $x=-1$ is off by a sign; my guess is the problem is meant to invoke the identity $\arctan(1)+\arctan(2)+\arctan(3)=\pi$

Comment: @Integrand sorry plese see edit

Comment: @Integrand didn't quite get what you meant $x=-1$ falls between $-\sqrt{2},1/3$

Comment: i had made another typo

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore i will stop commenting until you have resolved all the typos

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115204/discussion-between-albus-dumbledore-and-integrand).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\tan \left(\arctan x+\arctan(x+1)\right)=\frac{-2 x-1}{x^2+x-1}$$

$$\tan \left(\arctan 3-\arctan(x-1)\right)=\frac{4-x}{3 x-2}$$
provided that $\left(x (x+1)<1\right)\land \left(3 (x-1)<1\right)$ that is

$\frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{5}-1\right)<x<\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{5}-1\right)\land x\ne -1$

The equation becomes
$$\frac{-2 x-1}{x^2+x-1}=\frac{4-x}{3 x-2}$$
expanding and reordering
$$x^3-9 x^2-4 x+6=0$$
factoring
$$(x+1) \left(x^2-10 x+6\right)=0$$
which gives the solutions
$$x=-1,x= 5-\sqrt{19},x= 5+\sqrt{19}$$
$x=-1$ is discarded because the given equation is not verified

$$\arctan (-1+1)+\arctan(-1) +\arctan(-1-1)\ne\arctan 3$$

only $x=5-\sqrt{19}$ satisfies the constraint above therefore it is the only solution.

Comment: *Mathematica* confirms your answer ($+1$).

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore I edited my answer, which contained a minor error. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Thank you for taking time , again if you look  at the formula in my post shouldn't we take the case when $3(1-x)>1$ ie $xy>1$ .

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore The answer of your book is wrong. I got the formula here, a gold mine of informations with literaly thousands of formulae https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ArcTan/16/03/01/

Comment: ok , what iam saying is shouldn,t we consider other cases we may get more solutions

Comment: Nope. The unique solution is $5-\sqrt{19}$. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arctan%28x%2B1%29%2Barctan%28x%29%2Barctan%28x-1%29%3Darctan%283%29

Comment: thank you for giving the link , But why is that so, in any competitive exam like JEE i am supposed to conider all cases, or is there an easy way to eliminate the cases,Thank you for taking time in answering my comments,